# Помогите найти ошибку в коде. Наследование

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Помогите найти ошибку. Не работает код. Тут наследования классов. Класс Date базовый.

```
class Date {

    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

public :
    Date(int year, int month, int day)
{
}
};


class Person : public Date {
    char name;
    char surname;

public:
     Person(int year, int month, int day, char name, char surname)
   {

         cout << "Birthday"<< year << "." << month << "." << day << "." << endl;
         cout << "Name"<< name << "," << "Surname" << surname << endl;

    }
};

class Files : public Date {

    char filename;
    char extension;
    int size;

public:

    Files(int year, int month, int day, char filename, char extension, int size)
    {
        cout << "Date of creation " << year << "." << month << "." << day << endl;
        cout << "File Name is " << filename << endl;
        cout << "File Extension is " << extension << endl;
        cout << "File Size is"<< size << endl;

    }
};


class TextDocument : public Files, public Person {
    char discplace;
    char wayplace;

public:
    TextDocument( char filename1, char discplace1, char wayplace1, char name1, char surname1)
    {
        discplace=discplace1;
        wayplace=wayplace1;
        name=name1;
        surname=surname1;
        filename=filename1;
        cout << "Text Document File is" << filename << endl;
        cout << "Placing Disc" << discplace << endl;
        cout << "Placing Way " << wayplace << endl;
        cout << "Author is" << name << " " << surname << endl;
    }
};

class ArchiveItem : public Date, public TextDocument {
public:
    ArchiveItem(char discplace, int year, int month, int day)
    {
        cout << "TextDocument discplace is " << discplace << endl;
        cout << " The Date of Creation "<< year << "." << month << "." << day << endl;

    }
};
```

Comment: одну любую ошибку?

Comment: @Igor в классе Person

Comment: Выбирайте: 1. Персон это не дата. 2. Конструктор не вызывает базовый с соответствующими параметрами. 3. Конструктор `Date` никуда не запоминает параметры. 4. Конструктор `Person` никуда не запоминает параметры.

Comment: мне в от Date в Person нужно наследовать дату рождения (переменные year month day)

Answer (score 4):

Выбирайте:

1. `Person` это не `Date`.
2. Конструктор `Person` не вызывает базовый конструктор с соответствующими параметрами.
3. Конструктор `Date` никуда не запоминает параметры.
4. Конструктор `Person` никуда не запоминает параметры.
5. Имя и фамилия в `Person` состоят из одного символа каждое.

> мне в от Date в Person нужно наследовать дату рождения

Нет, Вам в `Person` нужна дата рождения как член класса.

Comment: а почему я не могу наследовать переменные год месяц и день как дату родждения в класс Person?

Comment: @MarynaSaid Вы можете человека хоть от табуретки унаследовать - есть сидение и ноги.

Comment: @MarynaSaid Но в Вашем случае, человек это не дата. Дата рождения должна быть членом класса `Person`.

Comment: так почему вы говорите что я должна эти переменные писать как отдельные члены класса?

Comment: @MarynaSaid У человека может быть только одна дата в жизни?

Comment: но мне нужно унаследовать. такое задание ЛР. Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Дата рождения только одна!

Comment: @MarynaSaid Ваш класс `Date` это не дата рождения, это любая дата. Я не знаю, что такое "ЛР".

Comment: Вообще выдает ошибку no matching func to call

Comment: @MarynaSaid  «такое задание ЛР» — передайте тому, кто придумывал такое задание, лучи ненависти от имени всего Stack Overflow :) Понапридумывают глупых заданий, а потом люди выпускаются из универов без понимания ООП...